# How can oscilloscopes be immune to radiated noise?

Tags: noise, antenna, oscilloscope, bandwidth

I have an oscilloscope which has a bandwidth of 500 MHz.

It means that all signal with a frequency under 500 MHz can be observed without (a lot of) distortion.

Noise radiated is said to begin at around some MHz; it depends on the size of the antenna/trace. In any case, even if the antenna is not equal to λ/4, there is still some coupling and it may be amplified by the different stages of the oscilloscope.

Without considering that the probe wire seems to be a good antenna, how can an oscilloscope be immune to radiated noise? Why don't I see any noise when I measure a DC signal, for example, despite the high bandwidth of an oscilloscope?

Comment: Nothing is immune but, what does immune mean; has an unnoticeable effect, has a slight effect or has a large effect. What source of radiation might be in the vicinity of your oscilloscope; will there likely be a significant one or, is it likely that there are none?

Comment: Well I would like to better understand how a trace is "immune" to a precise noise or not... It seems that the impedance of the antenna (source ?) has an effect and the impedance of the "load" should also have a link. That is what I would like to understand. I think I will do an other post :)

Answer (score 2):

Cables are excellent antennas for **common-mode signals** and oscilloscope cables are no exceptions. Luckily, the scope measures the differential signal between inner and outer cable conductors. Radiation has a hard time coupling more into one of the conductors than into the other.

It is not impossible though:

- Ground clip loops are notorious for picking up magnetic EMI.
- there are also loop antenna probes meant to pick up magnetic radiation
- likewise, there are E-field probes

Examples:

- touch your finger only on the inner conductor tip -> you will pick up loads of mains E-field noise and the scope will easily detect it (probably several Volts)
- hook the ground clip to the inner conductor tip, forming a makeshift loop. Then hold it near anything switching, e.g. switch mode PSUs or processors etc. you will easily detect many 100 mV magnetic noise.

How to make your measurement immune to noise is a broad topic. The most important advice is: use tight loops (ideally no loop, but a ground "spring") between the outer contact and tip.

Answer (score 1):

There are noises certainly.

- if your 500MHz oscilloscope is not the recent high resolution scopes from Rigol or Siglent, it will be probably 8-bit resolution. It will be hard to see the induced noise using such 8-bit oscilloscopes. Under 500MHz, the coupling can be considered zero for such non-sensitive oscilloscope inputs.
- Even for 12-bit high resolution scopes, main noise comes from analog frontend. Because of it, many key players in oscilloscope industry are making their own ASIC based analog frontend to minimize noises by frontend itself.
- So, why induced noise is smaller than frontend self-noise? The oscillocope's input impedence is normally 1Mohm. Exceptions are for RF aux inputs, such as Tektronix's MDO3x series, which is 50-ohm input. Even though coupling between trace and probe's ground wire are established, its impedence will be tens or hundreds ohms range. Thus, RF energy is not delivered correctly to 1Mohm frontend.

For an opposite situation example, think about EMI testing probe.
It has small number of rounds coil as probe end. And it is quite similar size range with normal probe's ground wire.
But such EMI probes are connected to 50-ohm RF input of spectrum analyzers or Aux input of advanced mixed domain scopes.

Comment: Why are Rigol or Siglent (of all) special in this regard 

Comment: 12bit oscope, only those two frontiers released last year. Other competiters didn't release yet. R&S released 4000 series but it's too expensive.

Comment: Here is an article from early 2020 discussing 12-bit scopes. https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/fundamentals-of-8-bit-versus-12-bit-oscilloscopes Doesn't even mention Siglent or Rigol :)

Comment: @PCBCrewEngineer When you say"Even though coupling between trace and probe's ground wire are established, its impedence will be tens or hundreds ohms range. Thus, RF energy is not delivered correctly to 1Mohm frontend." By "impedance" you mean the parasitic capacitor of the cable of the probe between the trace and probe's ground wire will be low ? In any case without considering cable of the probe, I can have a large input impedance of an electronic function into the oscilloscope which can couple some noises. Imagine the noise is capacitively coupled through a trace into the oscilloscope

Comment: At 500 MHz it seems possible

Comment: Also if the impedance between  trace and probe's ground wire is low as you said, it means that the oscilloscope is not able to measure signal @ 500 MHz due to the probe ?

Comment: Let me ask some quick question. What will be Lambda/8 single pole antenna impedance?

Comment: @PCBCrewEngineer I do not know ... I have no experience in RF and antenna ... I will take a look on it